# Filtering out a variable in R studio

Tags: filter

How do I filter out a particular piece of information from a data set, which I named invasives, so that it includes everything but that said info. For instance, from my subset data for stateCommonname I want to get rid of everything pertaining to the spotted lantern fly found in that column. This is the code I wrote for it, but I keep getting the data set to show info in regards to spotted lantern fly, which I want to exclude.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceJSf.png)

Comment: Please see [ask]. Show some code. Explain what you tried. [edit] the question to include these details with us.

Comment: Okay, I updated the info and added the picture of the code and my approach in the question section.

Comment: Be in the habit of providing a [mcve] as text in the body of the question. It also looks like this question could have been solved with some _debugging_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 'not' operator: '!' to flip the logic.

```
filter(invasives, !stateCommonName == "Spotted Lanternfly")
```

Note, it's better to include the code itself than a screen shot of it.

Comment: I was able to figure it out before, but thanks for taking your time out to answer! I will take note of that for future questions.